# Entity framework error ... property could not be set to 'System.Int16' value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have this Class:

```
public class PayTerm
{
    public int PayTermExternalKey { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the Database, `PayTermExternalKey` is `smallint` because it is related to the key of another system table which is `smallint`, in my program I have a grid where I save instances of the `PayTerm` class ... except correctly but when I go to recover the `PayTerm` list I have an error in EntiyFramework

> The 'PayTermExternalKey' property on 'PayTerm' could not be set to
>   'System.Int16' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'System.Int32'.

I looked in all the classes where I use the property and it turns out to be always int ...

**UPDATE**
I had created the table badly, now `PayTermExternalKey` is the right type, now the error no longer occurs.

Comment: Are you using Code First or Db first ?
Why can't you just set PayTermExternalKey to short instead of int ?

Comment: Db first...Because if I put int or short the error gives me anyway

Comment: I had created the table badly, now PayTermExternalKey is the right type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand much but I think you should change PayTermExternalKey's type in class PayTerm from int to short. Because System.Int16 is short type.

Comment: I had created the table badly, now PayTermExternalKey is the right type